# .htaccess Change root directory with exceptions for a list of directories

Tags: .htaccess

Hi, 
I have my .htaccess code that changes the root directory from public_html to a new-site folder and it's working perfectly.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com.au$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com.au$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !new-site/
    RewriteRule (.*) /new-site/$1 [L]
```

the issue with it is: I want to keep a few inner pages from the old site loading from the default directory.

```
https://example.com.au/load-this-from-the-old-site/
https://example.com.au/load-this-from-the-old-site/another-page/
https://example.com.au/etc/
```

The above pages are not directories they are pages requested from the old public_html/index.php file

Any help would be appricated

Answer (score 0):

Insert an exclusion condition in your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(new-site|load-this-from-the-old-site|etc)/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) new-site/$1 [L]
```